# Why doesn't the binary value match its hex representation in NASM x86?

Tags: assembly, binary, nasm

I'm trying to understand this in GDB where I see the following:

```
(gdb) print/t $eax
$2 = 1000000001001010000000011010
(gdb) x/4xb $eax
0x804a01a <testinput>:  0x41    0x42    0x43    0x44
```

This is essentially the ascii values "ABCD".  I'd like to get these values one byte at a time and have tried to start with getting the the first byte in $al.  However $al contains 0x1a.

First, how does the binary 1000000001001010000000011010 equate to 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44? (I would think 0x41 would equal 0100 0001 but I don't see that pattern above)
Second, why does $al contain 0x1a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at two completely different things. Your first command outputs the value of the `eax` register. Your second command outputs the value of a particular location in memory. There's no reason one should equate to the other in any way.

As the `gdb` help says:

> Examine memory: x/FMT **ADDRESS**.
>   ADDRESS is an expression for the **memory address** to examine.

As for your last question, the low byte of `eax` is `00011010`. `0001` is `1` in hex. `1010` is `a` in hex. So `0x1a`.